# tabletop object segmentation?

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

How can i get position of segmented objects in tabletop object segmentation ?

Or is there any package which can segment existing objects and returns their current position?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30320/tabletop-object-segmentation?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The result of the tabletop object segmentation is in TabletopDetectionResult.msg. If you look at this message, you'll see that you get a list of potential models. Each of them has a PoseStamped associated.

So to get the object position, once you've got the result, you can access the poses for each of your detected models:

```
result.models[i].model_list[j].pose
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-03-24**:
I have tested above instructions, now my problem is that i am just getting the position of the table! i think the objects on the table didn't segmented successfully! Do you know any other segmentation package?
Thanks for your help!